# How to get rowindex of dataGrid WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

Here am using the code in datagridview and it works fine.but how to get the rowindex in datagrid based on without selecteding the rows in datagrid in wpf.please help me to do.
below the code am tried:

```
private int GetRowIndex(string ID)
{
  int num = -1;
  //Get the row based on ID
  foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridVV in (IEnumerable)this.dataGridView.Cells)
  {
    if (dataGridVV.Cells[0].Value.Equals((object)ID))
        num = dataGridVV.Index;
  }
  return num;
}
```

Comment: why you need a row index in wpf?

Comment: becoz,to delete the row based on rowindex

Comment: this is in fact some kind of searching. So normally we have to do a linear search by looping through all the rows. It depends on the underlying collection. If it supports some method to find the row, you should use that method (for optimized performance). Otherwise looping is the only way.

Comment: What is wrong with using the SelectedItem and/or SelectedIndex properties?

Comment: You shouldn't work with WPF using WinForms-style. Work with bound collection, not with `DataGrid`.

Comment: Its for sending purpose,so that without selected the datagrid row,it want to delete after completes the sending

Comment: Your ItemsSource should point to an ObservableCollection and then all you have to do is to delete it there.

Comment: I guess that the row he wants to delete is not some kind of selected item. The user may enter some ID for the row he wants to delete, and then that ID is used to find the row..

Comment: @KingKing:no sir,the actual purpose is for sending ,after sending finished,the datagrid column contain a StudyUID(ie,here am passed a parameter as ID),based on which datagridreow is finished,that should be delete based on rowindex

Comment: sorry I don't really understand what you meant here. Anyway, what you have is just the ID. And you have to find the row corresponding to that ID. That's all. And as I said above, looping is the only way (even internally implemented by some supported method). You know SQL even has to loop, but it has some kind of indexing mechanism and makes the loop is very fast.

Comment: @KingKing the rowindex am needed for delete the particular datagrid row based on some condition.For that,how to get the row index of datagrid row without selecteditem

Comment: As @HenkHolterman already said, delete the item from the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: While am trying to delete from Itemsource it shows error as"datagrid operation is not valid while itemssource is in use"

Comment: @RajnathKumar: usually, `DataGrid.ItemsSource` is bound to an instance of any collection type: `List<T>`, `Collection<T>`, etc. Do not try to remove item from `ItemsSource` directly. Delete it from bound data collection instead.

Comment: I believe that @Bolu meant *delete the item from the [collection that is data bound to the] `ItemsSource`*. Take a look at my answer that demonstrates how to do that.

Comment: @Bolu While am using ObservableCollection<what given to here>

Answer (score 1):

@RajnathKumar, you need to use WPF properly... as your comments say, you shouldn't try to use it as if it were WinForms... it's *not* WinForms and trying to use it in that way will only cause you problems. This is how I would achieve your requirements:

First, data bind a data collection to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property (of a `DataGrid`):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" ... />
```

Note that this `YourCollection` property should be an `ObservableCollection` of any type that you want... regardless of the type, I understand that it will have a unique `Id` property. Therefore, your required item can be found *from the data bound collection* directly using some basic `LinQ`:

```
var itemToRemove = YourCollection.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == someIdValue);
if (itemToRemove != null) YourCollection.Remove(itemToRemove);
```

Comment: `First` will throw exception if there is not any match. There will not be any `null` value returned. What you should use is `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: +1 Oh my bad... thanks, I forgot the `OrDefault`... updating now.

Comment: For the sake of justice, bound collection should be `ObservableCollection` only if there's a requirement to update `ItemsControl` when collection was changed. Otherwise it colud be a `List<T>`, `Collection<T>`...

Comment: @Dennis... better safe than sorry. In my experience, there's often a follow up question regarding that, so now I just recommend using them all of the time.

Comment: Actually,am used a datatable as "datatableobject",an based on ur example,am given <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding datatableobject}"

Comment: Well try taking the data out of the old fashioned `DataTable` and putting it into a collection like I suggested.

Comment: How to make an observablecollection?plz help me,am tried 3days

Comment: While am give ObservableCollection<datatableobject> it shows error,why?

Comment: A `DataTable` is a collection of `DataRow` objects. An `ObservableCollection` is a collection of your choice. Take the data out of each `DataRow` and put it into another object, preferably a custom class, and then add them all to the `ObservableCollection`. This is my last visit to your question, which now has an answer.